# Windows Store : UWP Application publication

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am currently trying to publish my UWP application to the Windows Store, but I can't figure mt way around. I createdan account on Microsoft Partner Center but when I try to create an app, I'm prompted to sign a file with SignTool.exe, but when I do so, I'm told my certificate is not trustworthy.
Why should I do ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you uploading your package to the store directly? Please check this document first: [Generate an app package upload file for Store submission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#generate-an-app-package-upload-file-for-store-submission). You need to associate your app with the store before you could upload it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already followed that process, when I use the "Reserve App Name" button in VS 2019's dialog, I always get "An unexpected error as occured ... "

Comment: Could you please try to create a new app in Partner Center manually? Then you could associate the package with the app in the Partner Center via Visual Studio.

Comment: I already tried to manually create a new app in the Partner Center but when I do so, I am prompted to sign a file with Signtool.exe, and when I do it, I'm told the certificate I used isn't trustworthy

Comment: Could you please which document that you are following when you tried to create an app in the partner center?